# Collecting data from rotten tomatoes using python API

Tags: python, web-scraping

Im new to python and API and i try to collect data from this link:
https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_action__adventure_movies/

the data that i want is the first 25 movies and their info
and i have to use API

the code im tring is this:

```
result = requests.get('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_action__adventure_movies/').text
print(result)
```

and thats as far as i could get...(im very new)

the result is very long but this is an example from it

```
<td class="bold">8.</td>
<td>
    <span class="tMeterIcon tiny">
                <span class="icon tiny certified_fresh"></span>
                <span class="tMeterScore">&nbsp;92%</span>
            </span>
        </td>
<td>
    <a href="/m/dunkirk_2017" class="unstyled articleLink">
        Dunkirk (2017)</a>
</td>
<td class="right hidden-xs">461</td>
```

the info that i need from this is the rank(class="bold"), rating(class="tMeterScore") ,title(class="unstyled articleLink") and number of reviews(class="right hidden-xs").

so the problem is that i dont know how to get the data that i need from the result and i dont know if i even do it the right way (if there is a better way to get data)

Comment: You might have to use Beatifulsoup to scrape the data off the website

Comment: Is there an API? That doesn't look like an API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

For tables on simple web pages, `pandas.read_html` is great.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read all the page tables with a simple call
tables= pd.read_html('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_action__adventure_movies/')

# display the table shapes to manually select the corret one
print("Tables")
print('\n'.join([f"{i} shape:{t.shape}" for i, t in enumerate(tables)]))


# Selection of the table ('2' results from the manual observation, see previous comment)
table = tables[2]


# some data 
print('\n'.join(["", "Table:", "",
                 "Columns types:", str(table.dtypes), "", "",
                 "5 first and last rows:", str(table), "", "",
                 "First row:", str(table.iloc[0])
                 ]))
```

Output:

```
Tables
0 shape:(11, 2)
1 shape:(12, 2)
2 shape:(100, 4)
3 shape:(10, 3)
4 shape:(10, 3)

Table:

Columns types:
Rank                 float64
RatingTomatometer     object
Title                 object
No. of Reviews         int64
dtype: object


5 first and last rows:
     Rank  ... No. of Reviews
0     1.0  ...            525
1     2.0  ...            547
2     3.0  ...            437
3     4.0  ...            434
4     5.0  ...            392
..    ...  ...            ...
95   96.0  ...             93
96   97.0  ...            130
97   98.0  ...            324
98   99.0  ...            203
99  100.0  ...             66

[100 rows x 4 columns]


First row:
Rank                                  1.0
RatingTomatometer                     96%
Title                Black Panther (2018)
No. of Reviews                        525
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: the thing is that i need to do it with API (its for a job interview)

Comment: I do not know if there is an official API neither if it is public or if you need to get authorized API keys. On the other hand you can find non official python packages related to rottentomatoes.com.

Comment: can i "cut" parts from the result to get what i need? like searching data by key word and then cut it from result and put it in a list or something? and using request is not an API method?

Comment: Request retrieves a response of a site to a question. the question can be a simple url (in this case response is what the a browser will try to render)  or a API question (in this case response is a structured answer to the API query).